# regex include special character in pattern for re.finditer

Tags: python-3.x, regex

im trying to get a start and stop index number of a word inside a string using re.finditer.
for most of it my pattern working fine, but for a word with special character my regex giving me an error

Problem:

I tried:

```
a = " we have c++ and c#"
pattern = ['c#','c++']
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(pattern) + r')\b')
out = [ (m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in regex.finditer(a)]
```

Current Output:

```
error: multiple repeat at position x
```

Expected Output :

```
[(9,12),(17,19)]
```

for most of case my pattern working fine 
but word with special character I'm having a problem.
I'm not much familiar with regex, any one please help out of it, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:**

```
a = " we have c++ and c#"
pattern = [ r'\b{}(?=\s|$)'.format(re.escape(s)) for s in ['c#','c++']]
regex = re.compile('|'.join(pattern))
[ (m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in regex.finditer(a)]
```

**Details:**

The first problem is, special characters; you can escape special characters manually

```
'c\\+\\+', 'c\\#\\#']
```

or to simplify you can use [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), it would do that work for you

```
re.escape('c++, c##')
```

The second problem is,  word boundaries; they won't behave the same way for special characters  as they would for alphanumeric characters e.g. `\bfoo\b`

To quote from python docs

\b [word boundary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

> Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.
>   A word is defined as a sequence of alphanumeric or underscore
>   characters, so the end of a word is indicated by whitespace or a
>   non-alphanumeric, non-underscore character. Note that formally, \b is
>   defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice
>   versa), or between \w and the beginning/end of the string, so the
>   precise set of characters deemed to be alphanumeric depends on the
>   values of the UNICODE and LOCALE flags. For example, r'\bfoo\b'
>   matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or
>   'foo3'.

To make this work, you can use positive lookahead assertion

`r'\b{}(?=\s|$)'`

It looks for a whitespace `(\s)` character or end of the sentence `($)` after your pattern